# Can you help point out the issues in the code

Tags: apex, geolocation

This is a code I have done to fetch all the accounts near a *closedwonAccount*. I have fetched the *closedwonAccount* using a flow and called it to the apexclass using `@invocable` method.

I have debugged and confirmed that the ID of the record is obtained here. Now I have to query using this.

This is the code I have written but there are some errors in the query. Please provide a solution.

Here latitude and longitude are two variables  have used to store the latitude, longitude of the *closedwon accounts*. And I have used `billinglatitude` `billinglongitude` to find nearby accounts within 50km.

```
public class DistanceRecord {
    public class FlowInputs {
        @invocableVariable public String AccountId;
    }

    @InvocableMethod
    public static void getAcct(List<FlowInputs> requests){
        List<Id> IdsOfAccount = new List<Id>();
        for(FlowInputs request:requests){
            IdsOfAccount.add(request.AccountId);
            System.debug('IdsOfAccount'+IdsOfAccount);
        }
        String units='km';
        List<Account> accountList = new List<Account()>
        accountList=[SELECT Id,Name,BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude FROM Account
                     WHERE DISTANCE(GEOLOCATION(Latitude, Longitude), GEOLOCATION(BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude) :units)<30];
        System.debug('accountList'+accountList);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange! You mention "some errors". Please update your question with the exact errors, otherwise we cannot help you.

Comment: @SanderdeJong Yes I have updated it.My issue is in the query.Thanks

Comment: Please provide your code by pasting it into your question, instead os including it as a screendump

Comment: @LukasLunow Yes Updated

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! As Sander de Jong originally stated, please elaborate on *exactly* what you mean by "some errors": Are you getting any results? Are you getting unexpected results? Is there an actual error occurring? | Where are the `Latitude` and `Longitude` variables coming from which are used in your first `GEOLOCATION` call? Also, you are missing a comma between `...BillingLongitude)` and `:units`. (Although according to the answer from @FelixvanHove, you cannot use a bind variable for units.)

Comment: @Moonpie I had updated the code as FelixvanHove said and the errors are reduced.As you said the issues was in the syntax of the query+the latitude,longitude variables are still the errors remaining.I have stored them as formula variables in the flow and tried to call them into the apex class which is the issue.I want to somehow get the latitude and longitude of the closedwon Accounts and that is why I used these variables.

Comment: I've extended my answer as best as I can :-)

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I've understood your requirements correctly. The following might work as long as it is never called in bulk (untested):

```
Account a = [
    SELECT BillingLatitude, BillingLongitude 
    FROM Account
    WHERE Id =: requests[0].AccountId
];

List<Account> accountList = [
    SELECT BillingAddress, Name
    FROM Account
    WHERE DISTANCE(BillingAddress, 
                  GEOLOCATION(:a.BillingLatitude, :a.BillingLongitude),
                  'km') < 30
];
```

I've hard coded the unit, because according to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_geolocate.htm) Apex bind variables are not supported for units.

This is for demo purposes only. You will need to bulkify it to make it work reliably, i.e. make it work for the case it is executed with more than one "requests". You will want to take measures for the case that latitude/longitude are not known for the incoming Account. Etc.

Comment: Thanks for the help I have updated the code but when I debug a.latitude and a.longitude remains null and hence this error remains:An Apex error occurred: System.UnexpectedException: Your DISTANCE function is missing one or more parameters for Latitude, Longitude, or Location.      I can't figure out why the value isn't getting entered there.

Comment: You are missing a comma before `:units` in your `DISTANCE` function, which is why you're getting the parameters error.

Comment: @DavidCheng , this is not about the syntax of the original code anymore. The :units spec is not valid at all anyway.

Comment: @PJ , if a.BillingLatitude and a.BillingLongitude remain null, it means they _are_ null. Apparently the Account's coordinates are not updated in the database (maybe only assigned, but not saved), before the InvocableMethod is called.